# Unable to send notification from Bamboo to Microsoft Teams channel using webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks, bamboo, http-status-code-400

I have configured a MS Teams webhook in my bamboo server such that if the plan build fails then I should get a message on the configured teams channel. However, I am running into the following the error right now:

```
Exception message 400 : "Summary or Text is required.
```

The request headers is

```
[content-type:"application/json"]
```

The request body is

```
{
  "uuid": "XXXXXX",
  "timestamp": "2023-07-12 17:51:07 +0800",
  "notification": "Completed Plan Notification",
  "webhook": {
    "webhookTemplatedId": "2200174593",
    "webhookTemplatedName": "Build webhook"
  },
  "build": {
    "buildResultKey": "CSP-CSV-464",
    "status": "FAILED",
    "buildPlanName": "Combined Synthetic Position - CSP - Stress (VM)",
    "startedAt": "2023-07-12 17:46:47 +0800",
    "finishedAt": "2023-07-12 17:51:07 +0800",
    "triggerReason": "Manual build",
    "triggerSentence": "was manually triggered by jjain"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: It looks like the card does have an empty body-https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3aRx.png. Please check that the card has been constructed properly - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=cURL

Please check these threads which mentioned similar issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141349/ms-teams-incoming-webhook-generating-400-to-send-text-formats,, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753072/microsoft-teams-webhook-generating-400-for-adaptive-card